# Multiple game modes on one server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I'm about to start a Minecraft server, and I'd like to mimic some of the mechanics of a few larger servers on which I have played. For example I'd like to be able to set local game modes, so that one biome may be a survival area, while another is creative. I've been trying to find a way to do this, but unfortunately I haven't found anything. So I was wondering if anyone could help?

Comment: My guess would be that some of this might be done using bukkit plugins or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command blocks are going to be your best bet here if you don't want to use any mods. Several things that are worth noting:

- You can change a player's gamemode when they step over a pressure plate:

- `/gamemode 2 @p`
- gamemode 2 is adventure mode, @p is the nearest player. Place it in the doorway of a building you want to alter the gamemode to.

- You can give a player mining fatigue so they can't touch anything within the radius of the command block. Hook this up to a circuit that runs once a second.

- `/effect @a[r=100,m=0] 4 3 5`
- effect means you're applying a status effect, @a is all players in a radius of 100 blocks with gamemode 0 (survival), effect 4 (fatigue) for 3 seconds at a strength of 5 (they literally cannot mine anything, not even grass).

You could even change the gamemode for everyone in a certain radius (like a biome) so you could have a creative biome, a survival biome, and an adventure biome. If you did decide to do this, I hope you don't mind what players do outside these areas because they could enter a creative world biome and go off doing their own thing unless you implemented a way to stop them.

The [commands wiki page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands) has a ton of information on how you can customize your minecraft experience based on what you put into the blocks. I anticipate the larger servers you played on use plug-ins, however if you're looking to start something similar with just family/close friends, command blocks should be more than adequate.

Comment: You can use the same principle as the mining fatigue bit with the gamemode command. Something to the effect of `/gamemode @a[r=100] 2`

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/gamemode adventure @p`, `/effect give @a[gamemode=survival,distance=..100] mining_fatigue 3 5`

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard of Bukkit? Although I'm not particularly sure how the other people run their servers to match the description that you have made. Bukkit is a server program that involves a lot of plugins that could possibly allow you to customize it to match your description and more.